# Azure Go SDK - Guide for Multi Tenant Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sdk, azure-ad-b2b, azure-service-principal

I am new to azure and i am trying to implement multi tenant authentication using their go sdk but cant find anything similar in the sdk nor the go sdk docs.

I came across this article [Guidance for multi-tenant applications using the Azure Identity libraries](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/guidance-for-multi-tenant-applications-using-the-azure-identity-libraries/#additional-recommended-actions) that mentions how to implement it via the language sdk's but it does not contain any examples for golang.

What i'm trying to do is something similar to how its being done in .NET in this code snippet

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
{
    AdditionallyAllowedTenants = { "<tenant_id_1>", "<tenant_id_2>" }
});
```

Has anyone tried implementing this via the azure go sdk and found success?

Comment: *Did you get chance to look into* [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/extensions)

Comment: @RajeshM I couldn't find anything related to multi-tenant authentication here. Also there does not seem to be any extension libraries feature for the azure go sdk.

Comment: Please check the class ClientFactoryTests.cs in Azure.Extensions solution.

Comment: @RajeshM I could not find any file by the name of ClientFactoryTests.cs in the repo. Can you please point it out by providing the absolute link to that file?

Comment: Please check this [file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/extensions/Microsoft.Extensions.Azure/tests/ClientFactoryTests.cs)

Comment: @RajeshM Thanks for providing the link. I went through the code but couldn't find a similar implementation for Golang. 

I have already opened a github issue for the same here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/19726 on which i'm getting help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is finally made available in the azure go sdk. Below is an example code snippet on how to achieve this.

```
import(
  "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/azcore/arm"
  "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/sdk/resourcemanager/resources/armsubscriptions"
)

auxTenants := []string{"azure-tenant-id-1", "azure-tenant-id-2"}

cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(tenantID, 
clientID, secret,                                               
  // AdditionallyAllowedTenants prevents the credential from trying 
  // to authenticate in an unexpected tenant. All credential types 
  // capable of multitenant auth have this option. 
  &azidentity.ClientSecretCredentialOptions{
  AdditionallyAllowedTenants: auxTenants},)
  if err != nil { 
    // TODO: handle error
  }

// armsubscription is just an example, all ARM clients have this 
// same options API
client, err := armsubscription.NewSubscriptionsClient(cred,
  // client will add a token for each of these tenants to every 
  // request.                   
  &arm.ClientOptions{AuxiliaryTenants: auxTenants},
)
```

Unfortunately, this feature was not present in the azure go sdk at the time of asking this question.

I had later on, opened a GitHub issue for the same where i was presented with a custom workaround till the actual feature got shipped in the beta release of the go sdk.

Github issue reference - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/19726